# How do I configure http-server for history mode in Vue JS 2?

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vue-router, vue-cli, httpserver

I have a Vue JS application built in the directory `dist`. For running I use `http-server` installed globally by the command:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

I run the app with the command:

```
http-server dist
```

So I can reach the website on `http://localhost:8080`, it works correct. But in my app I have `vue-router` that is configured with history mode, so I should access the URLs like `http://localhost:8080/page1`, but the problem is `http-server` returns 404:

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/page1

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
accept-ranges: bytes
Date: Sat, 11 Sep 2021 12:41:53 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Content-Length: 0
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that the fix is to run `http-server` with the "proxy" option as a "Catch-All" redirect - `http-server -P http://localhost:8080? dist`
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do that without hard-coding the hostname?

Comment: What would you use instead of the hostname?

Comment: a relative link or something?

Comment: Relative to what ?!? The "proxy" option of http-server is used to specify where to look for those URL pathnames that do not exist in the local filesystem. And since you want all of these URLs to return your `index.html` you must specify where this `index.html` can be found. If you bind your http-server to something else than localhost - you should use that address as an argument for the proxy option. IF you bind http-server to 0.0.0.0 (the default) - then you can safely use `localhost` as the proxy argument.

Comment: Note: this only work on Node up to v 16. If you're on a later version, you'll have to downgrade.